# Imgproc.drawContours(....) not showing up

Tags: java, android, opencv

In my android app I get an image from the gallery as a bitmap with something like this

```
Bitmap bitm = getMyImage("Thanks!");
```

and I have a Mat called mat declared like this:

```
Mat mat = new Mat(bitm.getHeight(), bitm.getWidth(), CVType.CV_8UC3);
```

I'm trying to get contour areas from the image, which I've successfully gotten then draw it back on the original image with:

```
Imgproc.drawContours(mat, contours, -1, new Scalar(200,200,0), 2);
displayMat(mat);
```

If I use it like that, it works but the contours are drawn on a blank image which isn't what I want. I want it to be drawn on the original image. If I use

```
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitm, mat);
```

before the previous snippet of code, the displayed image is just the preprossed image without the 'Drawn' contours. Why?

Comment: I didnt work with android opencv yet, but I think I've read somewhere that they use 8UC4 images?!? so `new Scalar(200,200,0)` needs an alpha value too. Otherwise it uses default alpha value which will be transparent I guess. So put `Utils.bitmapToMat(bitm, mat);` before your code and change to `Scalar(200,200,0,255)` or `Scalar(200,200,0,0)` whichever means to be a non transparent alpha value.

Comment: @Micka Thanks! This was the reason it wasn't showing up. If you leave your comment as an answer I'll be sure to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asfaik Android uses images with alpha values, so `CV_8UC4` is the right data type.

So

```
Mat mat = new Mat(bitm.getHeight(), bitm.getWidth(), CVType.CV_8UC3);

Imgproc.drawContours(mat, contours, -1, new Scalar(200,200,0), 2);
```

displayMat(mat);

draws the contours correctly on an empty/blank `8UC3` image (if memory empty).

But if you want to draw on the input image by first converting `Utils.bitmapToMat(bitm, mat);` you'll overwrite your `8UC3` memory and replace it by `8UC4` data. After that you draw `Scalar(200,200,0)` which will use a 4th channel, but `cv::Scalar` automatically adds those channels with `default zero values`, so you draw your contours in transparent. So use `Scalar(200,200,0,255)` instead and it should give your expected results.

```
Mat mat = new Mat(bitm.getHeight(), bitm.getWidth(), CVType.CV_8UC3);

Utils.bitmapToMat(bitm, mat);

Imgproc.drawContours(mat, contours, -1, new Scalar(200,200,0,255), 2);
```

displayMat(mat);

The other method would be to convert the bitmap to 8UC3, but I'm not sure how to do that.